# first driver -- spi framework for linux

Tags: linux-device-driver

This is first time i am writing a driver for linux SPI framework for ADS7846.
Found this excellent tutorial to understand the concept of linux SPI :---
http://www.jumpnowtek.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=57&Itemid=62

It also have a sample co-de. 
https://github.com/scottellis/spike/blob/part3/spike.c

1> Few points which i was not able to get why we are using semaphore
befor accessing  -- spike_dev.user_buff.

do we really need semaphore ? Because at a time my application program willonly read() or write() or open() the driver ?

2> Also to select the chip select we are using :--
   /* specify a chip select line */

```
SPI_BUS_CS1
```

Here why we are not specifing which PORT will the CS - line be connected to ?

3> As what i have read spinlock should be used with interupt handler. Also what is the use of this spinlock in the driver. 
   Here we do not have spi Interupt handler.But while accessing -- spi_async & spi_device -- we are using spinlock ?

spin_lock_irqsave
   spi_async
spin_unlock_irqrestore

4> Also can we have multiple "protocol drivers" registered to same SPI device ?

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

2> it is could be mentioned in .controllerdata the bus num and chipselect is to enumerate the SPI devices

3> it is used for taks which can sleep